# X-devAPI not working inside of Google cloud SQL

Tags: mysql, mysql-5.7, google-cloud-sql, google-app-engine, node.js

I am tryng to use X-devAPI inside of Google cloud SQL but getting the following error from MySQL client

`comp@user:~$ sudo mysqlsh -u root -h XX.XXX.XX.XXX --mysql --dba enableXProtocol
[sudo] password for philo: 
Creating a Classic session to 'root@XX.XXX.XX.XXX'
Enter password: ~~~~~
Fetching schema names for autocompletion... Press ^C to stop.
Your MySQL connection id is XXXXX
Server version: 5.7.14-google-log (Google)
No default schema selected; type \use <schema> to set one.
enableXProtocol: Installing plugin mysqlx...
enableXProtocol: Error installing the X Plugin: ClassicSession.runSql: Access denied; you need (at least one of) the SUPER privilege(s) for this operation`

What am I doing wrong?